# How to set Theme in controller test in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I use themes on my cakePHP 2.6 project and would like to test my application.

I have a view file in `/app/View/Pages/view.ctp`
I overwrite it here `/app/View/Themed/Theme/Pages/view.ctp`

How can I change the `$this->theme` to get the result of the themed view?

I tried this (without result):

```
public function testView() {
    $this->theme = 'Theme';
    $url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view'));
    $options = array(
        'return' => 'contents'
    );
    $result = $this->testAction($url, $options);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($result);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine , what  the problem actually is?? You are already in access of view.ctp within Theme folder .

Comment: My code doesn't change the Theme.
I am guessing, that this is to late or simply the wrong place to change the theme.